# Result beyond while loop condition?

Tags: java

```
    double avg = (double)ListUtil.sum(list)/list.size();  
    k =10;
    while (avg <= k - 0.5) {
        list.add(k);
        avg = (double) ListUtil.sum(list)/list.size();
        System.out.println(avg);
    }
```

I have a while loop like above with `condition is <= 9.5`

Output

```
9.0
9.25
9.4
9.5
9.571428571428571
```

Why it run till `9.571428571428571` not `9.5` ?

Comment: Use a do-while loop

Comment: remove = from while

Comment: This result is expected - you tell the loop to continue when it reaches 9.5, with `avg <= k-0.5`, so the loop does exactly what you told it to do. The answer you picked as "the answer" has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: We should check if adding a value to the list will push the average out of the required state before adding it.

```
double avg = (double)ListUtil.sum(list)/list.size();
double editedAvg = avg;
k = 10;
while (avg <= k - 0.5) {
    avg = (double) avg + ((k - avg)/(double)(list.size() + 1));
    if(avg <= k - 0.5) {
        editedAvg = avg;
        list.add(k);
        System.out.println(editedAvg);
    }
}
System.out.println("Final avg: " + editedAvg);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/60uIiY)

The formula for adding a value to the average is taken from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/how-to-add-and-subtract-values-from-an-average

Also, you should really look into using a debugger which is probably available in your IDE - It will allow you to go step by step through you code and will help you figure out what step causes the wrong output.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

And for fun (but still a useful debugging technique no matter how good a programer you are) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Thank you to *dasblinkenlight* for pointing out a problem with the previous answer and for providing the demo source code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping one time too many. Try doing the calculation last so that the `while` conditional comes directly after it.

```
double avg = (double)ListUtil.sum(list)/list.size();  
k = 10;
while (avg <= k - 0.5) {
    list.add(k);
    System.out.println(avg);
    avg = (double) ListUtil.sum(list)/list.size();
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't change anything in terms of the calculation - the printout would not show `9.571428571428571`, yet that is what the value of `avg` would be after the loop.